# Prove that $M(|f|,S)-m(|f|,S)\leq M(f,S)-m(f,S)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Let $M(f,A)=sup\{f(x):x\in A\subseteq[a,b]\}$ and let $m(f,A)=inf\{f(x):x\in A\subseteq[a,b]\}$.

Given that $|f(x_{0})|-|f(y_{0})|\leq |f(x_{0}-f(y_{0})|\leq M(f,S)-m(f,S)$ for $x_0,y_0\in S$,
prove that $M(|f|,S)-m(|f|,S)\leq M(f,S)-m(f,S)$.

---

By the given inequality we see that $M(f,S)-m(f,S)$ is an upper bound of $\{|f(x_{0})|-|f(y_{0})|:x_0,y_0 \in S\}$.
I was given a hint providing that $sup\{|f(x_{0})|-|f(y_{0})|:x_0,y_0 \in S\}=M(|f|,S)-m(|f|,S)$.

However, I'm not exactly sure to go about proving it is in fact the supremum of $\{|f(x_{0})|-|f(y_{0})|:x_0,y_0 \in S\}$.

Could anyone clarify on how to prove that $sup\{|f(x_{0})|-|f(y_{0})|:x_0,y_0 \in S\}=M(|f|,S)-m(|f|,S)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $x$ and $y$ in your set
$$f(x) \leq \mathbf{sup} _{x}f(x)=M$$
$$f(y) \geq \mathbf{inf}_{y}f(y)=m \implies -f(y) \leq -\mathbf{inf}_{y}f(y)=-m$$
Add the two up to get

$$f(x)-f(y) \leq M-m.$$
Remember that this holds for all $x$ and $y$, so, in particular if we pick $y$ for $x$ and vice versa:
$$f(y)-f(x) \leq M-m.$$
The last two mean
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M-m.$$
Finally,

$$|f(x)|-|f(y)|  \leq |f(x)-f(y)| \leq M-m\ \ (*) $$
Holds for all real numbers by the triangle inequality.

Now, in (*) forget about the middle term. The left hand side is independent of variables, a real number really. Fix $y$, and take sup with respect to $x$:

$$ \mathbf{sup}_x|f(x)|-|f(y)| \leq M-m  \ \ \ (**)$$

Now, (**) holds for all $y$. Take inf with respect to $y$:
$$ \mathbf{sup}_x|f(x)|-\mathbf{inf}_y|f(y)| \leq M-m  \ \ \ (**)$$
But RHS is just what you wanted.
Done.
Done.

Comment: I understand the details you elaborated on here, but I'm mostly having trouble on making the jump from your details above to show that $M(|f|,S)-m(|f|,s)\leq M(f,S)-m(f,S)$

Comment: See the edited version now.

Comment: Ok. I'm beginning to see it now. Thank you.

Comment: This is a typical trick when dealing with mixed sup-inf problems: you do it in steps; fixing one variable at a time.

Please also declare my answer as the solution so that the question leaves unanswered posts.